# Is there a way to turn off how open windows lock to the monitor?

Tags: windows-10

I have a program that doesn't work well even with my resolution set at max. However all I really need to do is have the ability to move the window up/down a bit without it snapping back in place. Is there a setting I can turn off or a program I can run to get rid of the screen snap?

Thanks for your time,
Shane

Comment: First result for `windows 10 disable screen snap`: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-turn-snap-on-or-off